# MX record with only one dot, possible?

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

Lets say I have the following DNS active for domain example.com (leaving out ttl)

`example.com MX 0  .`

Does it mean that the MX record does point to `example.com`?  That server with name `example.com` will handle mail for `example.com` domain?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An `MX` record consisting of only a single dot `.` is a Null MX as defined in [RFC 7505](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7505). It means that the domain doesn't accept any email.

Comment: It still needs a preference of `0` too, it can not be just a dot.